# Qual a melhor forma de fazer a leitura de um arquivo XLS?

Tags: c#, .net, arquivo, xls

Gostaria de saber a melhor forma de fazer a leitura de um arquivo XLS em C#.

Consigo tratá-lo da mesma forma que trato um table do banco de dados?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15793442/how-to-read-data-from-excel-file-using-c-sharp isso responde sua pergunta?

Comment: Alternativa: abrir o XLS e salvar em um formato aberto, como CSV, etc. Assim, a maioria dos front-ents de DB podem importar automaticamente. Se tiver centenas de planilhas, pode ser inviável, mas se for adicionar uma ou outra ocasionalmente, basta converter ou mesmo educar os users a fazerem a exportação correta. Lembrando que você tem que pensar em como vai lidar com fórmulas.

Comment: Uma boa alternativa é a Biblioteca ClosedXML que está disponível gratuitamente no Nuget. Segue link de como utilizar.
[http://www.tretaneverends.com.br/blog/ler-excel-com-c-visual-studio-baby-steps/](http://www.tretaneverends.com.br/blog/ler-excel-com-c-visual-studio-baby-steps/)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Qual a melhor forma não posso dizer, até porque o que é melhor para um caso pode ser pior para outro. Posso dar opções.

Além do método já citado pelo Reiksiel, existem algumas outra opções:

Existe a biblioteca [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus) que é uma das utilizadas para essa função.

Pode usar a biblioteca [Excel Data Reader](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader) que é um projeto *open source* que faz o trabalho duro por você. Nunca a usei mas tem muita gente que usa.

Também existe a [excellibrary](https://code.google.com/p/excellibrary/). Não tenho maiores informações.

Existe ainda a [Free .NET Excel API](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/691749/Free-NET-Spreadsheet-Control) que [e uma versão "capada" de uma software comercial. Só para testar mesmo e ver se vale a compra.

Se usar o LINQ é muito importante para você, tem o [Linq to Excel](https://github.com/paulyoder/LinqToExcel). Não conheço ninguém usando.

Existem algumas formas de tratar as planilhas como XML. Um [exemplo no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1544150/221800).

Algumas destas soluções funcionam apenas com o XLSX. Não sei se o seu caso é estritamente para o XLS.

Como você não deu parâmetros, posso dizer que existem diversos componentes comerciais de diversas empresas bem conhecidas no mercado. Uma pesquisa simples te levam até eles.

Não vou citar as soluções mais "porcas" :)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: É que assim, eu faço estágio e outro dia meu chefe recebeu uns dados em .xls pra passar para o banco de dados (SQL SERVER 2008) e ele me fez usar o Delphi7 pra isso porque ele se sente mais confortável ao tratar dados com ele, mas como meu foco é C# e trabalhamos apenas com ele aqui (usamos delphi apenas nesta ocasião) é a linguagem que eu estudo, etc, etc, queria saber como fazer isso com C#, se possível utilizando os recursos nativos (?) do .net, acredito que o link que o Reiksiel passou atenda minha necessidade.

Comment: @CaiqueC. Ok. Algumas desta bibliotecas são só facilitadores mesmo. Outras permitem alguns recursos extras que o OLEDB teria dificuldade. Mas aí vai da sua necessidade mesmo. Tem que tentar o mais simples e depois ver se precisa de algo mais sofisticado. Eu nem ia responder mas achei que valia o complemento. Se a dele é a melhor, não esqueça de aceitá-la como resposta certa. Mas também não tenha pressa. Pode surgir uma resposta melhor ainda.

Comment: é que ainda sou bem inexperiente, ainda tenho um pouco de "medo" desses facilitadores. Preciso de um tempinho livre pra testar, se funcionar vou marcar como resposta certa. Obrigado pela atenção :)

Comment: Vou marcar como resposta correta porque é a que mais se enquadra na minha pergunta.

Answer (score 11):

Existe a opção de usar o OleDB e ler o arquivo do Excel como uma tabela em um banco de dados...

Um exemplo.....

```
string con = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\temp\test.xls;Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;'"
using(OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(con))
{
    connection.Open();
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("select * from [Sheet1$]", connection) 
    using(OleDbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
         while(dr.Read())
         {
             var row1Col0 = dr[0];
             Console.WriteLine(row1Col0);
         }
    }
}
```

Este exemplo usa o `Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0 provider` para abir e ler um arquivo Excel.
No entanto, se o arquivo for do tipo xlsx (a partir de Excel 2007 e versões posteriores), então você precisará baixar os componentes do Microsoft Data Access e instalá-lo na máquina. O `provider` será `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;`. Não sendo necessário possuir o Office na máquina.

Fonte: [Aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15793442/how-to-read-data-from-excel-file-using-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

Usando `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
// add reference - COM - Microsoft Excel 15.0
// http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-read-excel.htm
namespace excelop
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    public Form1()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btlerxls_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      Excel.Application xlApp;
      Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
      Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
      Excel.Range range;

      string str;
      int rCnt;
      int cCnt;
      int rw = 0;
      int cl = 0;

      xlApp = new Excel.Application();
      xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(edarquivo.Text, 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
      xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

      range = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange;
      rw = range.Rows.Count;
      cl = range.Columns.Count;


      for (rCnt = 1; rCnt <= rw; rCnt++)
      {
        for (cCnt = 1; cCnt <= cl; cCnt++)
        {
          str = (string)(range.Cells[rCnt, cCnt] as Excel.Range).Value2;
          memo1.Text += rCnt.ToString() + " " + cCnt.ToString() + " " + str + "\r\n";
        }
      }
      xlWorkBook.Close(true, null, null);
      xlApp.Quit();
      Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkSheet);
      Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkBook);
      Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);
    }
  }
}
```

[Referência](http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-create-excel.htm)