# Leitura de PDF .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Estou pesquisando a muito tempo uma forma de ler um documento pdf que contem tabelas de Insumos da Sinapi e salvar os dados em minha base de dados, e não faço a minima de como fazer, alguém poderia dar uma dica?

link do pdf [aqui](http://www.caixa.gov.br/Downloads/sinapi-a-partir-jul-2014-sp/SINAPI_Custo_Ref_Composicoes_SP_042015_Desonerado.pdf)

link do pdf mais complexo [aqui](http://www.dnit.gov.br/servicos/sicro/norte/norte/2015/ac-01-15-sem-desoneracao.rar)

Answer (score 3):

Até é possível ler, porém, só é viável se o PDF manter uma formatação "limpa" (com linhas e colunas bem definidas, sem multilinha, etc). Mesmo assim uma mudança no layout pode quebrar todo o código feito para leitura do PDF.

Na maioria dos casos uma solução viável seria transformar o PDF num outro formato: HTML, TXT, Xls, etc.

[Aqui](http://www.pdfonline.com/convert-pdf-to-html/) tem uma boa ferramenta online para conversão PDF para HTML que facilitaria bastante a leitura em várias linguagem (incluindo C#). Veja um exemplo de como ficaria seu documento:

**Documento convertido em HTML:**

[image: Documento convertido em HTML]

Como o documento não possui tabelas com padrão definido, a conversão torna o HTML complicado para leitura, por exemplo com o [HtmlAgilityPack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack)

Uma das ferramenta para conversão de PDF em um formato "legível" para um linguagem de programação é a [Able2Extract](http://www.baixaki.com.br/download/able2extract.htm)

Veja as configurações e como ficou seu documento convertido para XLS:

> É a melhor opção para conversão pois permite alinhar/selecionar
>   somente o texto necessários

**Configuração: Seleção somente da tabela e colunas para conversão**
[image: Configuracao]

**Uma ferramenta gratuita para extrair dados PDF:**
[PDF Multitool utility](http://bytescout.com/products/pdfmultitool/index.html)
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Tabela convertida, agora basta criar código para leitura do XLS**

> Com certeza o código para ler XLS é bem mais prático do que para PDF
>   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
string con = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\temp\test.xls;Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;'"
using(OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(con))
{
    connection.Open();
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("select * from [Sheet1$]", connection) 
    using(OleDbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
         while(dr.Read())
         {
             var row1Col0 = dr[0];
             Console.WriteLine(row1Col0);
         }
    }
}
```

**Alguns dos vários exemplos disponíveis na WEB:**
[Aqui](http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/1895/lendo-um-arquivo-do-excel-%E2%80%9Cxls%E2%80%9D-com-csharp.aspx) e [Aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15590/qual-a-melhor-forma-de-fazer-a-leitura-de-um-arquivo-xls)

Comment: Muito bom, obrigado pela dica!, Meu principal problema é que preciso que a pessoa entre com o pdf no sistema, pois ele é atualizado todo mês, então tem que ser um procedimento bem simples.

Comment: De nada @RonaldoAsevedo marque a resposta como `aceita` caso seja satisfatória.

Comment: Meu principal problema é que preciso que a pessoa entre com o pdf no sistema, pois ele é atualizado todo mês, então tem que ser um procedimento bem simples.

Comment: Entendo, leitura de PDF não é algo simples devido a complexidade do mesmo, vide seu caso. Existem SDKs, a maioria pago, que conseguem ler PDFs, porém como expliquei é complicado ler os dados de forma confiável. Eu já tentei fazer algo parecido com o que você perguntou, no meu caso a melhor solução foi converter o PDF. Uma dúvida o PDF será sempre o mesmo "modelo" ou haverão outros? @RonaldoAsevedo

Comment: São varias tabelas, mas elas não mudam, só valores ou é acrescentado mais itens, eu adicionei no post principal uma outra tabela chamada SICRO que é mais complexa.