# Exportar Tabela do banco para XLSX sem Interop

Tags: c#, vb.net

No código abaixo foi atribuída uma *Query* para a variável *sQuery*.

Preciso de alguma forma exportar essa *Query* para **Excel** utilizando algum recurso disponível para *C# WebForm* **que não seja o Interop**.

```
 Dim da = New OleDbDataAdapter(sQuery, ConnectionString)
    Dim dt = New DataTable()
    da.Fill(dt)
    Dim GridView1 As New GridView()
    Dim iTipoExport As Byte


        Dim sstr As String

        Session("Arquivo") = sNomeArquivo

        CaminhoDiretorio = Server.MapPath("~/Download/" & sNomeArquivo & ".txt")

        FileOpen(1, CaminhoDiretorio, OpenMode.Binary)
        sstr = ""
        For k As Integer = 0 To dt.Columns.Count - 1
            sstr = sstr & dt.Columns(k).ColumnName + "^"
        Next
        sstr = Mid(sstr, 1, Len(sstr) - 1)
        sstr = sstr & vbCrLf
        FilePut(1, sstr)

        For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
            sstr = ""
            For k As Integer = 0 To dt.Columns.Count - 1
                sstr = sstr & dt.Rows(i)(k).ToString() + "^"
            Next
            sstr = Mid(sstr, 1, Len(sstr) - 1)
            sstr = sstr & vbCrLf
            FilePut(1, sstr)
        Next

        FileClose(1)
        AppExcelExport = CreateObject("Excel.Application")            
        AppExcelExport.Workbooks.OpenText(CaminhoDiretorio, StartRow:=1, DataType:=Excel.XlTextParsingType.xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=Excel.XlTextQualifier.xlTextQualifierNone, Other:=True, OtherChar:="^")
        WboExcelExport = AppExcelExport.Workbooks(1)
        WshExcelExport = WboExcelExport.Sheets(1)
        WshExcelExport.Select()
        RngExcelExport = WshExcelExport.Rows(1)
```

Comment: Veja se ajuda https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15590/101

Comment: Entendi, eu consigo utilizar o EPPlus ou Linq to Excel para converter um csv em xlsx?

Comment: Talvez, precisa ver se atende o que precisa, mas acho que sim.

Comment: Acredito que as opções desse post sejam para gerar um Excel, no caso eu preciso exporta-lo do meu data table.

Comment: A pergunta claramente pede para converter um arquivo Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia, você pode usar a biblioteca .NET gratuita chamada EPPlus. Abaixo esta um tutorial simples de como usar, não coloquei o código aqui pq é grande.

http://www.macoratti.net/16/04/vbn_gdvxls.htm

Answer (score 0):

Eu utilizo um componente que cria o XLSX diretamente pelo OpenXML não necessitando o Excel instalado na máquina ou servidor.

Segue exemplo:

http://www.tretaneverends.com.br/blog/visual-studio-c-gerando-planilhas-excel/